# Return key when Emacs running inside a terminal

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs

I have re-assigned the RETURN key to exit the insert state in Evil mode.

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map [return] 'evil-normal-state)
```

But this does't work with `emacs -nw` in terminal. Any way to make it work?

Comment: Terminals do not send `[return]`.  Use `(kbd "RET")` which will work in and out of terminals. Note that you can ask Emacs -- `C-h k` would have told you how that key was described.

Comment: Writing vectors with keys isn't the cleanest ways to define keybindings, `kbd` allows you to use the Emacs notation for keys, and it will make your init file more readable for everyone, including you.

Comment: @phils Thanks! And thanks for the tip with `C-h k`.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 OK. Thanks. I will keep that in mind!